# Does AngularJS uses XMLHttpRequest 2.0?

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest

As certain browsers do not yet support XMLHttpRequest 2.0 I'd like to understand which of my customer I need to warn upfront as we are moving from JQuery Mobile to AngularJS

Comment: Why not open up the code and take a look?  Don't most of the mobile browsers use the some version of Webkit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making Ajax calls is well-understood 10 years now. I'm sure the Angular folks have done it properly. It should not worry you.

BTW, Angulars Ajax implementation is based on:

```
var XHR = window.XMLHttpRequest || function() {
  try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0"); } catch (e1) {}
  try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0"); } catch (e2) {}
  try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); } catch (e3) {}
  throw new Error("This browser does not support XMLHttpRequest.");
};
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for Angular's `$http` service, it does not.

> - The `$http` service is a core Angular service that facilitates communication with the remote
> - HTTP servers via the browser's {@link https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest
> - XMLHttpRequest} object or via {@link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP JSONP}.

And the docs found [here](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.%24http) also say that it does not.  You shouldn't have any compatibility problems with making ajax requests from within Angular, from any desktop or mobile browsers.